# No output in Isabelle output panel

Tags: installation, isabelle

When I first install Isabelle 2021 in windows 10, It always shows an  I/O error. In the Theories panel, it shows the prover is inactive instead of ready. Whatever I input, there is just nothing appears in ouput panel.

Does anyone knows why? Thanks a lot.[waht the computer shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8BGq.png)

Comment: Can you share the full error message? Maybe it's a problem with the installation path. I always extract my Isabelle to something like `C:\Isabelle\Isabelle2021` on Windows.

Comment: Well I have reinstalled the system and it worked, hhh.